# In a conversation, do native speakers people call each other by name?

Tags: names, conversation, convention

I've noticed a particular behavior in the frequency of mentioning the person's name we're talking with.

I'm Italian, in my language we are used to calling each other by our first names during a conversation, simply to enforce a message or to confirm the communication channel between the talkers.

But, I've seen that English native speakers do this less often, if at all.
Instead, Indian people tend to use the person's name a lot during a conversation, maybe even more so than Italians.

- Can someone confirm this practice?
- Is frequently referring to  the addressee's first name  in a conversation perceived as a sort of privacy invasion?
- Have there been any studies on this phenomena?
  Or was this an isolated case due to the speakers I had experience with?

Comment: Fascinating question. In comparison to Italian, English is well known for using fewer quasi-linguistic hand gestures to accompany speech. But the amount of use of the other's person name I haven't thought of.

Comment: This would be very interesting, if true! Though since this is a cross-language analysis & comparison, I wonder if our friends at [Linguistics.se] would be in a better position to address it?

Comment: I believe you're right. I was reviewing a set of video interviews just a couple of days ago and was startled to hear the interviewer name his interlocutor with virtually every question. In that case, of course, the speaker was concerned to provide a variety of cut points for editors. In ordinary circumstances we may name the addressee at the beginning of an utterance, particularly if we need to distinguish which of two or more people is being addressed, but only rarely in the middle of an utterance or longer colloquy.

Comment: I often wish other people would use names more often in conversation... sometimes other people in the conversation don't know them or have forgotten. ;_;

Comment: @StoneyB: Interviewers/interviewees on radio/TV definitely tend to *name* the addressee more often than would be normal in most contexts. I expect the primary reason on the *interviewer's* side is simply that he needs to keep dropping in such references for the benefit of listeners/viewers who've only just tuned in. The interviewee might do it for various reasons (imply honesty thru intimacy, for example), but I imagine most of it is still for the benefit of a third-party audience rather than the actual co-conversant.

Comment: @StoneyB what language were these interviews in that you were reviewing?

Comment: It's such a phenomena (IMO), that when a pushy salesperson uses my name repeatedly in a sales pitch, I find it unsettling at best and downright annoying at worst!  Interesting question!

Comment: In particular, I'd like to know if naming the addressee often would be perceived as a sort of privacy invasion to native speakers, and therefore harm the conversation. Thank you for your comments so far.

Comment: @Mitch It was middle-America stuff, an elevator operator throwing questions at a farmer -- which is what made it so surprising.

Comment: Pier, not a privacy invasion, but like Kristina said unsettling: I'd interpret overuse of my name as the other person trying to ingratiate themselves to me because they really know my name like a friend (but a friend would obviously not do that).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "The interviewee might do it for various reasons" - one of the tactics that was taught in media relations training was to use the interviewer's name in the middle of difficult replies in order to prevent the wider use of the video. The idea was that mentioning the person's name would spoil the tape for other broadcasters. In the age of YouTube, I suspect this kind of advice is now irrelevant.

Comment: This question has obviously elicited a lot of interest. Would it be interesting to reopen it?

Answer (score 2):

Almost only before the conversation to get the other person's attention. This is evidenced by the fact that we have to teach business students to try to find ways to use someone's name a few times after meeting in order to be able to remember it. This is often tricky because, if done poorly, it is very easy to sound and feel unnatural doing it.

If someone frequently used my name to address me while talking to me it would be very uncomfortable and make me defensive; it would feel aggressive. It would be less so if there we were in a larger group discussion and names were needed to address questions, though.

Comment: I too feel defensive (am I being sold to, or patronized?) when [my interlocutor uses my name in 1-to-1 conversation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264588/mentioning-someones-name-in-1-to-1-conversation).