# Mentioning someone's name in 1-to-1 conversation

Tags: names, conversation

When only two interlocutors are communicating in a face-to-face or equivalent setup without the need to get the other's attention, there is no necessity to mention the other person's name.

Yet sometimes one of the speakers uses the other's name. I personally find this condescending ("I know what you mean, Dan"), or at best intense ("You're so awesome, Dan"), but I'm not a native speaker and would like to learn more about the connotations of this usage.

Comment: I wouldn't feel it condescending...unless the situation or tone of voice gave me that impression...perhaps tell us the situations you are quoting so we can better answer.

Comment: Mostly, using the name like that serves as an intensifier.  Precisely what is intensified is highly variable, however.

Comment: Sad to see this question nominated for closing, given [the interest that a related question has received](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253086/in-a-conversation-do-native-speakers-people-call-each-other-by-name). From the comments there, I'd like to echo that hearing my name overused puts me on the defensive against a sales pitch

Comment: Exactly. It has to be used quite sparingly, or else it begins to sound odd.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the situation, but adding in the name can be helpful for several reasons. As you indicate, condescension may be one such reason, but that is a subset of a larger class of reasons meant to convey intensity. Consider, for instance, "Dan, we have a problem!" Or, "I'm so in love with you, Dan." Both of these are using the name to engage the other side of the conversation on a more urgent or more intimate level.

Note, too, that there is the additional usage in written language whereby the writer can convey clarity about who is talking without having to use additional notation.

> "What do you think about going up to Diamond Lake?"
>
> "Oh, Dan! Do you remember how much fun we had camping there?"
>
> "I certainly do, Shirley."
>
> "Let's go again."

This can be used not only to convey information about who the speakers are but to set up a particular style of writing or conversation.

Comment: No, that last line goes "I'm Samantha!!"